# Div covering text input in chrome and user cant select it

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

On one of my web sites there is a text input box on the left for search.

http://wiki.guildwars2community.com/

However in chrome you cant select the input as if you *right click>Inspect* element it selects a div.

Whats strange is the links and buttons underneath it work fine.

Any ideas or is this a chrome bug? I have tried setting the z-index to 999 but thats no good.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'display:block;' and it should work..